# Service Stack Ormlite c# UpdateOnly not updating with GUID ID

Tags: c#, sqlite, guid, ormlite-servicestack

I am using Ormlite SQlLite v4.0.5, and i have an object which uses a Guid as an identifier.  Therefor i created a property 'Id' which returns the Guid as the Id:

```
public Guid Id { get { return this.ContactUID; } }
```

I am attempting to do a partial update of this object using `db.UpdateOnly` but it doesn't update when i specify the Id using the Guid - UpdateOnly returns 0.  Here's what i am doing:

```
var icnt = db.UpdateOnly(new ContactSend { IsDirty = false }, cs => new { cs.IsDirty }, cs => cs.ContactUID == key);
```

However, if I use another property on the object which is an int to identify it it WILL update successfully, and return 1 from UpdateOnly.  Using SQLite Database Browser i can see the change, and i can see that there is a Id column of varchar(800) which contains the keys.

Is there a limitation on what datatype i can use for an Id, or specifically, does UpdateOnly not support Guid keys for building the where clause?  (I haven't attempted to view any sql output)

Thanks